# 500 Internal Server error with SMTP on wordpress custom template

Tags: php, wordpress, email, smtp, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using SMTP to send an email. for that, I used the WP Mail SMTP plugin ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/ ) I tested the mail with the WP Mail SMTP plugin and it works. Now I want to send a mail with the SMTP function which I created in the WordPress template

Here is my template file code

```
<?PHP 
/* Template Name: smt */
get_header(); 

        require '/PHPMailer/class.PHPMailer.php';
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host = "******";
        $mail->Username = "******";
        $mail->Password = "***********";
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $mail->Port       = 587;
        $mail->From = "no-reply@*****.com";
        $mail->FromName = "zaata";
        $mail->AddAddress('anaiycvktquiech@gmail.com');
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = "zaata Varification code";
        $mail->Body    = "testmail";
        $mail->IsHTML(true);                      
        if(!$mail->Send())
        {
            echo 'false';
        }
            echo 'send';
    }

 ?>
```

It show me itsugestion.com/:1 GET *******.com/dev/smt/ 500 (Internal Server Error)  in console

Please help me how can I set up the SMTP in WordPress template
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check the [debug log](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) to get more details about that 500 Internal Server Error and report back what you find.

Comment: with wp-mail-smtp installed you can just use the `wp_mail` function as written in the discription of the plugin `WP Mail SMTP plugin easily resolves email delivery problems by improving and changing how your WordPress site sends email. We reconfigure the wp_mail() function to either use proper SMTP host credentials or leverage a built-in SMTP mail provider.`

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment to your question its best to just use `wp_mail()` as the plugin makes it use smtp, as for the error 500 your missing a the else part of the if statement

```
<?PHP 
/* Template Name: smt */
get_header(); 

        require '/PHPMailer/class.PHPMailer.php';
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host = "******";
        $mail->Username = "******";
        $mail->Password = "***********";
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $mail->Port       = 587;
        $mail->From = "no-reply@*****.com";
        $mail->FromName = "zaata";
        $mail->AddAddress('anaiycvktquiech@gmail.com');
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = "zaata Varification code";
        $mail->Body    = "testmail";
        $mail->IsHTML(true);                      
        if(!$mail->Send())
        {
            echo 'false';
        } else {
            echo 'send';
        }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Function.php

```
   add_action('wp_ajax_mail_before_submit', 'my_function');

function my_function(){
    include_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php' );

    // check_ajax_referer('my_email_ajax_nonce');
    if ( isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "mail_before_submit" ){

   //send email  wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments ); 
   wp_mail($_POST['toemail'], $_POST['headline'], $_POST['message'], 'Headline Hospowork');
    echo 'email sent';
    die();
        
    }
    echo 'error';
    die();
}
```

JQuery

```
let data = {
  toemail: thesenderEmail, // change this to the email field on your form
  action: 'mail_before_submit',
 _ajax_nonce: nonce,
  headline: 'Invitation',
  message: 'Hello'
 };

$.post(__wanted__api.ajaxurl, data, function (res) {
  console.log('Got this from the server: ' + res);
});
```

This is what worked to me. but my problem is the wp_mail() is still return true. even the SMTP got an error or did not really send. What I want is wp_mail() should not proceed if the SMTP got an error.

if you add that

```
if(!$mail->Send())
 {
  echo 'false';
 } else {
 echo 'send';
}
```

That produces the Ajax error on the console.

Now this is my config in wp-config.

```
define( 'SMTP_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com');
define( 'SMTP_USER', 'yourSmtpEmail');
define( 'SMTP_PASS', 'yourPassword');
define( 'SMTP_FROM', 'yourSmtpEmail');
define( 'SMTP_NAME', 'yourSmtpEmail or any');
define( 'SMTP_PORT', '465');
define( 'SMTP_SECURE', 'ssl');
define( 'SMTP_AUTH', true );
```

They work all fine except handling the SMTP Error before wp_mail() is to send.